# MATLAB: Avoid poor quality matlab videos

Tags: matlab, animation, video, plot

I create a video of my plot series as below:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
r0=1;
theta=0:0.01:2*pi;
a=0.2;
psi=0;
writerObj = VideoWriter('shapes.mp4'); % Name it.
writerObj.FrameRate = 1; % How many frames per second.
open(writerObj); 
for k=1:3
    pause(1);

    r=r0+a*sin(k*theta+psi)+a*sin((k+1)*theta+psi)+a*sin((k+2)*theta+psi)+a*sin((k+3)*theta+0.8*pi);
    figure();
    x=r.*cos(theta);
    y=r.*sin(theta);
    plot(x,y);
    axis([-2 2 -2 2]);
%     axis equal
    grid on

    %%%%%%%%% Finding Area %%%%%%%%%%%%%
    A = polyarea(x,y);
    title({'line1',['Area = ' num2str(A)]})
%     title(['Area = ' num2str(A)]);

    set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer');
    view(2)
    frame = getframe(gcf);
    writeVideo(writerObj, frame);


    close all
end
close(writerObj); % Saves the movie.
```

But when you watch the video it has poor quality (by poor quality I mean, the quality when you export matlab plots in a jpeg format for instance).

For matlab plots people usually export in .eps format so that they save high quality plots and use them in their report or presentations.

What is an equivalent way (.eps in plot saving) for video making in matlab to preserve a good quality.

Comment: Could you at least vote up to my question if you find it useful for the community so that it will be viewed by more people, and at the end I might get this question answered? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `VideoWriter`? You're using the default settings. Have you tried increasing `'Quality'` or using a different encoder like `'Archival'` or `'Uncompressed AVI'` or `'Indexed AVI'`?

Comment: I have now improved the quality by setting the video recorder window size to a large window by the command: "figure('position', [70, 70, 900, 900])" ; and I made the text size of the labels large and I made the background white by the command "set(gcf,'color','w');".

With the same conditions I tried 'Archival' and 'Uncompressed AVI' and 'Indexed AVI', but since their background is .jpeg they did not improve the video quality.

Comment: Did you also adjust `'Quality'`? I believe the default is only 75 out of 100.

Comment: @horchler I even tried quality to be 100 but it did not help unfortunately !